# Why tomcat AJP connector need to send GET_BODY_CHUNK message to Apache mod_jk

Tags: tomcat, ajp

Why tomcat AJP connector need to send GET_BODY_CHUNK message to Apache mod_jk while reading request body. Why doesn’t it make use of Request Content-Length header already sent to it to decide how much body it still has to read from mod_jk.

Is it required to have some throttling capability in tomcat i.e. tomcat container will send this message if it is ready to take and process the next AJP packet.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no guarantee that the declared body length and the actual body length are the same. There are multiple reasons why they may be different including:

- invalid request
- request aborted during upload